# Setting VisualState on ItemsControl item Templates

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate that is bound to a data item. The ItemTemplate is quite complicated and I have added some visual state to it so that I can change it's appearance.

I want to be able to switch all the items VisualState to another state of my choice, on an event that occurs outside the ItemsControl.

How can I go about doing this? I've tried using the VisualStateManager.SetState, but this relies on a control, rather than a template, which seems to be all I can get via WaveItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i).

Regards

Tristan

Edit:

Here is my data template for the individual items. If you note the triggers I have set up, it handles the MouseEnter / MouseLeave of the template itself. I'd like to wire these up to the ItemsControl MouseEnter / MouseLeave, without writing any code. Is there a way to do this?

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LineTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="LineGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3">

        <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
            <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" By="-100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Line.Y2)" Storyboard.TargetName="lineTop"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" By="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Line.Y2)" Storyboard.TargetName="lineBottom"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="lineTop" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="lineBottom" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Line.Y2)" Storyboard.TargetName="lineTop" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="{Binding BottomValue}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Line.Y2)" Storyboard.TargetName="lineBottom" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="lineTop" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0.495" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="lineBottom" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ExpandedHighlight"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
                <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="Expand" StateName="Expanded"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="Collapse" StateName="Normal"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Line Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lineTop" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="{Binding Brush}" Y1="{Binding TopValue}" Y2="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Line.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleY="1"/>
            </Line.RenderTransform>
        </Line>

        <Line Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lineBottom" VerticalAlignment="Top" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="{Binding Brush}" Y1="0" Y2="{Binding BottomValue}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0.5">
            <Line.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleY="1"/>
            </Line.RenderTransform>
        </Line>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have also tried using the following binding:
SourceObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"

But this displays a message: "Type is not supported in a silverlight project".

Comment: You would better provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

In [Thomas Danemar's Blog](http://tdanemar.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/using-the-visualstatemanager-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern-in-wpf-or-silverlight/) there's an example of class to hold and switch `VisualState`. It's implemented by binding `VisualState` to attached property inside your ViewModel and them just set it to desire value. *You can even bind it `TwoWay` mode.*

Comment: Ok, that sounds like it would work, but it's far from ideal, as I don't really want to access the items directly. I was hoping to use a tunneling event tied to a trigger.

Comment: The blog post seems to be focused on implementing this for a UserControl. I just have a template.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger
                SourceObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                EventName="MouseEnter">
                <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="Expand" StateName="Expanded"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger 
                SourceObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                EventName="MouseLeave">
                <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="Collapse" StateName="Normal"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```